# Saving to SD card in KitKat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am working on an Android tablet application that is being used by law enforcement.  I had the tablet backup all the data to an external SD card.  I wanted to be able to recover data from the card in case the tablet got destroyed while the police officers were fighting crime.  I used this code to store the backup:

```
File file = new File("/mnt/extSdCard/" + NewOrLoad.directoryName + "settings.dat");
    try {
        bW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)); 
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(dreform); 
        bW.write(json);
        bW.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

It worked fine.  Unfortunately the newest batch of tablets purchased are running KitKat and this code doesn't work anymore.  The only solutions I found involve rooting the tablets, which is just not feasible in my case.  Is there a workaround?

Comment: [No](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/14VUiIgwUjY/UsxMYwu02z0J). You're out of luck.

Comment: ...if you are trying to write *anywhere* to the SD Card. However, you can use `getExternalFilesDirs()` to write app-private data to the external SD card. You might want to check whether this can be moved from one device to another, to access this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It worked fine

Only for devices where `/mnt/extSdCard` existed and was writeable. This is outside the bounds of the Android SDK, and there is no guarantee that any device will honor that specific path. Perhaps you were in a controlled environment, with a single device model, where making this assumption was (relatively) safe.

> Is there a workaround?

As 323go mentions in the comments, you are welcome to [use `getExternalFilesDirs()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs%28java.lang.String%29) (note the plural). If there is more than one element in the resulting list, the second and subsequent entries will be for "secondary external storage" such as removable cards. You can read and write from this directory without any required permissions.

There is also [`ContextCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html), which offers a `getExternalFilesDirs()` implementation that works all the way back to API Level 4. It will only ever return one value on devices running less than API Level 19, but it allows you to skip version checking yourself, as plenty of API Level 19+ devices will also only return one value (e.g., they do not have an SD card slot populated with a card).

I recently wrote [a series of blog posts](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) attempting to clarify the storage situation. You may be particularly interested in the one on [removable storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: Thanks.  If I use getExternalFilesDirs() will everything be deleted if I try to move the sdcard to another device?

Comment: @clavio: AFAIK, the files should remain on the card. However, they will not be available to the app if the card is removed. And if you uninstall the app, the files will be removed from the card, if the card is available.

Comment: Lately I tried a HTC M8. This has kitkat. With es fileexplorer i could copy files to every location in sdcard. How would that be possible?

Comment: @greenapps: I know of at least one hack to get around parts of the limitation, but that will probably be locked down in an update.

Comment: This was no hack. The device came right from the shop.

Comment: @greenapps: No, I was referring to something that ES File Explorer could use to get around parts of the limitation.

Comment: It was an old version of es fileexplorer. From long before kitkat.

Comment: @greenapps: Then you will have to ask HTC or the authors of ES File Explorer

Comment: But they don't know the hack you know. So you better tell yourself.

Comment: Are you still there? Now I got a tablet with KitKat 4.4 and getExternalFilesDirs() delivers only the (internal) external files dir. Nothing removable although I put a micro SD card in it and also OTG connected a flash drive. At inspection my app can read and explore the card at /mnt/external_sd but cannot write to it. The directory /mnt/external_sd/Android is not created by the OS. Also not after reboots. So my app can nowhere write on this card. This is not what I had understood. Under /storage there is sdcard0 but no sdcard1 or something else for the card.

Comment: I'm not sure if I would rely *solely* on `getExternalFilesDirs()` until KitKat is the oldest Android in use by users (maybe 4-5 years from now) since there are tons of devices with secondary storage that are not running >= KitKat