# Android: Retrieve all extrenal directory path

Tags: android, storage

On my android 4.4 android smartphone, there are two external storages. I can retrieve the path of the first one with the following code
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Morpho_triage";

But I have
/storage/sdcard/
/storage/extSdCard/

How can I know how much storage are available, and how can I retrieve the second path?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

cédric

Comment: Probably there is no function for that. But you could try getExternalFilesDirs() (note dirs). That gives a Files array. Please report what it gives.

Comment: Well I can't find out how to use this fuction. I tried to pass as arguments "", null, "/". I ends up getting a IO exception. According to other posts there is no solution for that, so I will test the phone model et use hardcoded pass. My application will be installed only on 3 different smartphone so I can afford that. :) Anyway, Thanks for your help!

Comment: Think you can use `File dirs[]=getExternalFileDirs(getApplicationContext());` targetting KitKat and otherwise `File dirs[] = ContextCompat.getExternalFileDirs(getApplicationContext());`. Read about `ContextCompat` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429544/saving-to-sd-card-in-kitkat Please report.